# How to resize array of structs?

Tags: c

I have an array of structs that I have defined in a header file:

```
struct table { 
    otherStruct *list[16];
}
```

Now I want to be able to resize this array, change the size of the array, or dynamically allocate an array that can replace (or join) the original list in "table" once a condition is met. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: you'd better use dynamically allocated arrays from the beginning. realloc() docs is your friend.

Comment: No, you'll wanna write a function to do it.

Comment: when you say use "dynamically allocated arrays from the beginning" should I malloc the list of otherStructs from the beginning in the headerfile in the struct definition?

Comment: no, you can't do that syntactically. I told you to write a function to allocate memory. You can't write: struct { type **array = malloc(x); } it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `list` an `otherStruct **`:

```
struct table { 
    otherStruct **list;
}
```

Now you can `malloc` it to be as big as you want and `realloc` at will.

Comment: Faster and prettier than mine, you win :)

Comment: This seems very reasonable. Is there any way I could potentially put in a variable in to "otherStruct *list[newVarHere];" and do it via this method?

Comment: @angrymonkey No, the length of the array is part of its type (and hence part of the struct's type). You can either have a fixed unalterable size or use dynamic sizes and malloc everything.

Answer (score 1):

Change the array to a otherStruct ** and malloc a group of (otherStruct *) to the new size of your array.  Be sure to free it as well as this will be a new alloc on top of your old ones.